# How do i cut down the number of rows by a column in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

Example data:

```
  dept    category   quantity  price
  1         r           s        t    
  1         .
  1         .           .
  1
  1
  1
  2
  2
  2
  2         .
  2         .
  2
  3
  3
  3
  3         .           .        .
```

I want to cut the number of rows for each 'dept' column as per the following:

```
  if(dept == 1) keep only 2 rows
  if(dept == 2) keep only 4 rows
  if(dept == 3) keep only 3 rows
```

The final data frame should look like:

```
dept    category   quantity  price
  1         r           s        t    
  1         .
  2
  2
  2
  2         .
  3
  3
  3
```

How do i do this easily?

Answer (score 1):

Another way without using any additional package:

```
df <- data.frame(dept=c(rep(1:3, each=5)), # exemplary data.frame
                 data=sample(letters, 15, replace=TRUE))
rows_to_keep <- c(2, 4, 3)
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$dept), function(subdf)
   subdf[seq_len(rows_to_keep[subdf$dept[1]]),]))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be using plyr. Make first a matrix that shows how many rows you want to keep for each value of dept, e.g `a <- cbind(1:3, c(2, 4, 3))`. Then use

```
library(plyr)
ddply(data, .(dept), 
    function(d) head(d, n = a[,2][which(a[,1] == d$dept[1])]))
```